# How to Investigate the difference between query execution times?

Tags: performance, sql, oracle

I have a simple query, when executed directly in SQL Developer Studio (It's an Oracle Database) takes around 4 seconds.

But when executed via my Java code it takes around 20 seconds.

I'm using Spring JPA and using the `@Query` annotation with `native=true`. I'm measuring the time using a custom annotation and Aspect.

So far I could not find any reason why this can happen. Any suggestions on how it can happen or a method on how to diagnose the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Network latency is a thing.  Is the database server on the same network or is it in a cloud or something?  If the results are significantly large, then in addition to the 4 seconds it takes to launch the query, it'd have to send it as well.

Comment: @Neil thanks for the comment. But I'm running the SQL Developer Studio on my machine too, so the same latency should apply right?

Comment: Yes, there would still be a latency assuming the database isn't on your computer.  Have you considered adding an index for the fields you're filtering with?

Comment: There are already indices. And that wouldn't explain the reason for the difference right?

Comment: It wouldn't explain the difference, but 4 seconds still leaves something to be desired.  Is the web application on your computer as well?  The difference is 16 seconds from the actual query and your Java program on the same computer?

Comment: Check any varchar2 field indexes. Depending on the JDBC driver, they may need to be unicode indexes else Java may ignore the index and do a table scan. The execution time difference you are seeing sounds like indexes are not being used.